# Connecting IntelliJ with Google Drive on both MacOS Monterey and Win11

Tags: windows, git, macos, intellij-idea

Since I use both a mac and a windows pc I finally wanted to use google drive as a main source for files, so that I could have easy access on both systems. Most of the time there ain't any problems, which is very nice.

Currently i am struggleing to with IntelliJ, since I want to have the file saved, as stated above, in the Google Cloud so that i can easily open it and work on it.

I already installed Git on both systems and i already tested that i can work on the selected file on both systems. The changes that i made are also displayed on both, so that is all fine.

The problem here is that it always shows this error:

on mac:
Invalid VCS root mapping
The directory /Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/intellij_projects is registered as a Git root, but no Git repositories were found there.

on windows:
Invalid VCS root mapping
The directory G:\My Drive\intellij_projects is registered as a Git root, but no Git repositories were found there.

Just gonna add that i am just beginning to Code, so my understanding of all this is very limited. I dont even know what this VCS is and where it should point to. So help in any way or form is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do not put a Git *repository* in a cloud-synced folder. It *will* get damaged, eventually. You can put a *working tree* in such a folder. I don't use IntelliJ and don't know what its complaint here is about, but Git is very particular about its own files and letting iCloud, Dropbox, or Google Drive mess with those is a recipe for disaster (usually not right away, usually Murphy's law means the disaster happens right before the Big Demo or whatever).

Comment: This seems wrong.  Putting your files into GitHub in the cloud and accessing them from your local disk after a pull request seems to be the right way to me.  Accessing the files over a network will be too slow.